# Why does a const update a property via the spread operator?

Tags: javascript

During a code review, it was pointed out that I could use spread operator and a constant to update an object:

```js
const props = { 
  hairColor: 'brown',
};

const hairColor = 'red';
const newProps = { ...props, hairColor};

console.log(newProps); // -> hairColor now equals 'red'
```

The question is, how does this work?

I understand how actually passing an object works:

```
const newProps = { ...props, { hairColor: 'red' }};
```

But how does it know to update `hairColor` with the value 'red'? A quick test shows it is using the variable name, but how?

```js
const props = { 
  hairColor: 'brown',
};

const colorOfHair = 'red';
const newProps = { ...props, colorOfHair};

// -> hairColor still equals 'brown'
// with new property 'colorOfHair'
console.log(newProps);
```

Comment: This is called [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ES6 [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). When you write `name` in an object, it's a shortcut for `name: name`. So

```
const newProps = { ...props, hairColor};
```

is short for

```
const newProps = { ...props, hairColor: hairColor};
```

This is unrelated to the spread operator, the same thing happens if you write:

```
const newProps = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2, hairColor };
```